# MSMQ virtual directory not created under Default Web Site

Tags: http, iis-7, msmq, virtual-directory

On the application server (windows 2008 r2) we have our site (XYZ) hosted in IIS. Our site XYZ uses port 80 and 443. We had removed Default Web Site from IIS since we didnt need it. Now we want to use MSMQ with Internet Messaging.

I Googled and found that MSMQ setup is designed in such a way that "MSMQ" virtual directory will always be created under default web site. So I added Default Web Site manually and set hostname for it (without hostname it wouldn't start as XYZ also uses port 80) and did IIS reset. Then enabled MSMQ HTTP feature, however, "MSMQ" virtual directory still gets created under our site XYZ.

Note: XYZ was created before enabling MSMQ HTTP support. I am not sure if the sequence matters!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like setting host-name for default web site did a mess. I removed host-name and set site (default) to work on port 8080. Then referred it like http://server:8080/MSMQ and internet explorer returned HTTP 501 error which is what I wanted. Tried posting actual message too and yes it worked.

Answer (score 1):

May have to change the website ID.
This [Blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2009/01/20/unable-to-install-msmq-http-support-0x80070003.aspx) should help.

Comment: In windows 2008 site ID can be changed using website > advanced setting in IIS. So I changed XYZ id to 2 and Default to 1. Then installed msmq http support. MSMQ virtual directory now got created under Default Web Site. Restarted server. As expected XYZ logs are going into W3SVC2.

However, when I navigate to http://server/MSMQ in internet explorer, I get "This page can’t be displayed" error. I should be get "501 - Header values specify a method that is not implemented" IF msmq was installed and is working properly. Surprisingly the log entry gets created under W3SVC2 and hits XYZ.

Comment: When I do http : //server/MSMQ it does not hit default web site instead hits XYZ. Confirmed this by stopping XYZ, post which it gives 404. 

Note - I could not add this statement to 1st comment due to length restriction.

Comment: Sounds like something confused in the IIS metadata. You might be able to work out what that is using ADSUTIL and checking the parameters. Unfortunately not something I have any real experience with.

Comment: up voted your suggestion as changing site ID was definitely required to get MSMQ dir created under proper site. Provided final answer   below.